# Django form ignoring 'required' value

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a date range form to use in my Django views.  In some of the views I use it in the date range is required, but not in others so I need the form to accept a `required` key word. I'm having trouble getting my form to recognize `required=False`.

The Django form:

```
class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    initial_start_date = kwargs.pop('initial_start_date')
    initial_end_date = kwargs.pop('initial_end_date')
    required_val = kwargs.pop('required')
    input_formats = kwargs.pop('input_formats')

    super(DateRangeForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['start_date'].initial = initial_start_date
    self.fields['start_date'].required = required_val
    self.fields['start_date'].input_formats = input_formats
    self.fields['end_date'].initial = initial_end_date
    self.fields['end_date'].required = required_val
    self.fields['end_date'].input_formats = input_formats

  start_date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':"form-control text-center"}))
  end_date = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':"form-control text-center"}))
```

It's used in my Django view like this:

```
def Nominal_Request(request):

  initial_end = Utils.addToDatetime(datetime.today().strftime("%Y/%m/%d"),weeks=6)

  form_dict = {}
  arg_dict = {}
  message = message = {'last_url':'Nominal_Request'}

  if request.method == 'POST':
    daterange_form = DateRangeForm(request.POST,required=False,initial_start_date=None,initial_end_date=initial_end,input_formats=dateFormats)

    if 'Range' in request.POST:

        if daterange_form.is_valid():
            #process the dates here....
            WS = daterange_form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            WE = daterange_form.cleaned_data['end_date']
            #date processing continues....

        args = {'Start':WS,'End':WE}
    return Request_Results(request,args)

  else:
    daterange_form = DateRangeForm(required=False,initial_start_date=None,initial_end_date=initial_end,input_formats=dateFormats)

    form_dict.update({'daterange_form':daterange_form})

  return render(request,'InterfaceApp/Request_Nominal.html',form_dict)
```

It displays fine, but Django still thinks that both of the date range fields are required and won't let me submit the form with one or both of the fields empty.
[image]

Why is it not picking up on my `required` arg?

Comment: What's the form error say? Can you make sure that it's the `required` fields that blocking you from submitting your form not some other errors? Check this by doing `print daterange_form.errors` after you call `daterange_form.is_valid()`.

Comment: @ShangWang It never gets to `daterange_form.is_valid()`, or even into `request.method=='POST'`, because Django won't let me submit the form without filling in the date field.

Comment: That's impossible. If your `required` failed the form submission, it will be failed by `daterange_form.is_valid()`. If you are not reaching even `request.method == "POST"`, then the error is somewhere else. Can you post your error full stacktrace if you have an error? If you don't even have an error, you might not hitting the `Nominal_Request` method at all.

Comment: @ShangWang There is no visible error in either my terminal or the developers console.  When I try to submit the form I get a little popup (show in the picture I added to the question).  I know I am getting to the `Nominal_Request` method because my form is displaying on the screen, the `request.method` just always remains `GET` because Django won't let me submit the form with no date field input.

Comment: Post your related html for the form please. Also post the javascript if you have any if that's not too much.

Comment: @ShangWang it appears that setting it using `self` does not work.  When I set it like so `start_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=False,widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':"form-control text-center"}))` then it works.  But that means that I cannot set the required value outside of the form definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101621/discussion-between-shang-wang-and-kdubs).